# Apache rotatelogs program parameter

Tags: windows, apache, logging

I am running apache on Windows Server 2008 R2 and piping the access logs to "rotatelogs.exe" as follows:

```
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l logs/access/log 1M" common
```

This works as expected.  Now, in version 2.4, rotatelogs introduced the -p parameter:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html

-p program

> If given, rotatelogs will execute the specified program every time a new log file is opened. The filename of the newly opened file is passed as the first argument to the program. If executing after a rotation, the old log file is passed as the second argument. rotatelogs does not wait for the specified program to terminate before continuing to operate, and will not log any error code returned on termination. The spawned program uses the same stdin, stdout, and stderr as rotatelogs itself, and also inherits the environment.

I want to be able to do something similar to this:

```
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l -p bin/myscript.bat logs/access/log 1M" common
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l -p bin/myscript.vbs logs/access/log 1M" common
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l -p bin/myscript.exe logs/access/log 1M" common
```

** either bat, vbs, or exe, not all of them

When configured, the old and/or new file name is passed to the script.  Then this would trigger some post processing.

Has anyone successfully implemented this feature in a Windows environment?